# getCurrentFocus is null when trying to hide the keyboard

Tags: android

I have a RelativeLayout nested inside another RelativeLayout. By default, it is hidden. When user clicks a button, the nested RelativeLayout becomes visible. This layout contains an EditText. When user is finished typing, I want to hide the keyboard:

```
<RelativeLayout
 ...
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/cameraEmoji"
        android:contentDescription="@string/camera_emoji"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_image_black_24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/cameraText"
        android:layout_marginStart="57dp" />


    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/emojiTextView"
        android:background="#80444444">
        <EditText
                android:id="@+id/actionEmojiText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:background="#FFF"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/finishText"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_complete_emoji_text"
                android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
  ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

The activity:

```
cameraText = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.cameraText);
        cameraText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                emojiTextView = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.emojiTextView);
                emojiTextView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                final EditText actionEmojiText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.actionEmojiText);
                actionEmojiText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
                        if (id == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_UNSPECIFIED) {
                            emojiTextView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);


                            View view = MainActivity.this.getCurrentFocus();
                            if (view != null) {
                                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
                            }

                            dropTextIn(actionEmojiText);
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

`getCurrentFocus` returns null but the keyboard remains visible. How can I hide the keyboard after typing in the EditText field?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered what appears to be the issue. `getCurrentFocus()` was returning null because the item I had focused I had set to `View.INVISIBLE` before invoking `getCurrentFocus()`. Consequently, the view was no longer visible and thus no longer focused.

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.setFocusable(false);
editText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
```

try to add these two properties to EditText, It will hide keyboard whenever you touch any other view after typing to Edittext